# How to create a faceted graph with multiple Min and Max points that are grouped

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I want to create a graph with multiple `min` and `max` points that are grouped by `month` and `year`.

My dataset `trythis3`:

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("Feb", "Apr", "Jun", "Aug", "Oct"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 2003L, 2007L, 
    2011L), Temperature = c(10.1717660661212, 19.1113251384721, 
    14.80103145439, 8.59164858808079, 6.86800188715349, 9.55507283803179, 
    15.6577982450023, 16.25518817037), color = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), color1 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), groups = structure(list(Year = c(1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 
1998L, 2003L, 2007L, 2011L), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

A look into this as a `data.frame`:

```
  Month  Year Temperature color color1
  <fct> <int>       <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> 
1 Oct    1994       10.2  FALSE FALSE 
2 Aug    1995       19.1  FALSE FALSE 
3 Jun    1996       14.8  FALSE FALSE 
4 Apr    1997        8.59 FALSE FALSE 
5 Feb    1998        6.87 FALSE FALSE 
6 Apr    2003        9.56 FALSE FALSE 
7 Jun    2007       15.7  FALSE FALSE 
8 Aug    2011       16.3  TRUE  FALSE
```

How I calculated the `col` `color` and `color1` which are the `min` and `max` values for the variables `Month` and `Year`:

```
trythis1 <- prac1 %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(color = (min(Temperature) == Temperature | max(Temperature) == Temperature))
trythis2 <- prac1 %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(color = (min(Temperature) == Temperature | max(Temperature) == Temperature))
trythis3 <- cbind(trythis1, trythis2)
trythis3 <- trythis3[, c(-5, -6, -7)]
```

A sample of the `data.frame` `prac1`:

```
    Month Year Temperature
1     Jan 1994  5.11379276
2     Feb 1994  3.21683318
3     Mar 1994  7.78435180
4     Apr 1994  8.37781038
5     May 1994 10.97117575
6     Jun 1994 15.06396991
7     Jul 1994 19.06792551
8     Aug 1994 16.84395137
9     Sep 1994 13.28449477
10    Oct 1994 10.17176607
11    Nov 1994  9.87512853
12    Dec 1994  6.23880411
13    Jan 1995  4.39990197
14    Feb 1995  6.37256581
15    Mar 1995  5.57871938
16    Apr 1995  9.09780864
17    May 1995 11.83570263
18    Jun 1995 13.85246862
19    Jul 1995 19.19339040
20    Aug 1995 19.11132514
21    Sep 1995 13.90945926
```

How I thought it would work with this code:

```
ggplot(trythis3, aes(x = Month, Temperature, group = Year)) + geom_line() + geom_point(aes(color = color)) + geom_point(aes(color = color1)) + facet_wrap(~Year) + scale_color_manual(values = c(NA,c("red", "blue")))
```

The output:
[image]
This is what it should look like (Apologies for the paint edit):

[image]

Comment: Use two data frames for the plot. Use `prac1` for the line, and for the point layer use data in a long format, with one column indicating "type" with values "Max Month", "Min Month", and "Max Year".

Comment: I think one thing that's missing here is making the categories you are interested in mapping.  You have 5 categories you want to have colors for (if you count NA), but you only make two categories (TRUE and FALSE).   You could do this with something like `case_when()` (or a nested `ifelse()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two data frames for the plot. Use prac1 for the line, and for the point layer use data in a long format, with one column indicating "type" with values "Max Month", "Min Month", and "Max Year":

```
year_summ = prac1 %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  arrange(Temperature) %>%
  slice(1, n()) %>%
  mutate(type = c("Min Year", "Max Year"))

month_summ = prac1 %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  arrange(Temperature) %>%
  slice(1, n()) %>%
  mutate(type = c("Min Month", "Max Month"))

prac1_summ = bind_rows(year_summ, month_summ) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("Min Month", "Max Month", "Min Year", "Max Year"))) %>%
  arrange(type)

ggplot(prac1, aes(x = Month, Temperature, group = Year)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = prac1_summ, aes(color = type)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green")) +
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

[image]

---

Using this data:

```
prac1 = read.table(text  = "    Month Year Temperature
1     Jan 1994  5.11379276
2     Feb 1994  3.21683318
3     Mar 1994  7.78435180
4     Apr 1994  8.37781038
5     May 1994 10.97117575
6     Jun 1994 15.06396991
7     Jul 1994 19.06792551
8     Aug 1994 16.84395137
9     Sep 1994 13.28449477
10    Oct 1994 10.17176607
11    Nov 1994  9.87512853
12    Dec 1994  6.23880411
13    Jan 1995  4.39990197
14    Feb 1995  6.37256581
15    Mar 1995  5.57871938
16    Apr 1995  9.09780864
17    May 1995 11.83570263
18    Jun 1995 13.85246862
19    Jul 1995 19.19339040
20    Aug 1995 19.11132514
21    Sep 1995 13.90945926", header = T)

prac1$Month = factor(prac1$Month, levels = month.abb)
```

Comment: If I wanted to create range bars instead of points indicating the min and max values how could this be done? Also, I have been trying to include the values of the `min` and `max` values of `Year` and `Month` onto the graph, by the plotted `point`. I have used `geom_text(aes(label=round(Temperature), 2))` but they're just gathered at one `point` at the same place on all graphs, can this be done with an arrow or line indicating where it is?

Comment: Maybe ask a new question for the errorbars with another paint mock-up. What x position would you want temp?

Comment: For the text, make sure you're using the same `prac1_summ` data frame. It should inherit the most recent aesthetics for `x` and `y` position. Also make sure you're not missing a parenthesis... `geom_text(aes(label=round(Temperature, 2)))`

Comment: Ah yes! I will try to figure our the error-bar plot myself otherwise, it may be a future question if it hasn't been answered already. By adding `data=prac1_summ` onto `geom_text` did the trick. However, `round` didn't work so I had to round the `Temperature` from the `data.frame` `prac1_summ` by doing this: `prac1_summ <- ddply(prac1_summ, .(Month, Year, type), summarise, Temperature=round(Temperature,2))` My only issue is that the data labels now sit on the points rather than near them. Is there a way to position these around them with a line pointing to the coloured dot?

Comment: Round should work fine, you probably have a small syntax error. Adding `geom_text(data = prac1_summ, aes(label=round(Temperature, 2))) +`  to the code in my answer works fine.  Use the `nudge` argument to adjust the labels. If you want labels with lines/arrows, I think the `directlabels`  package does that, but I'm not familiar.

Comment: Also, you're already using `dplyr` - don't mix with `plyr`. Stick with `dplyr`.

Comment: Yes you're right about `round` I made that error previously by placing the `digits` outside the brackets, I fixed this but was too hasty and hadn't corrected myself. I have only practised `directlabels` today so If it works I will figure it out. Also `nudge` should do the trick after reading `?geom_text`, and thanks for the tip about `plyr` and `dplyr`!